# error handling issue in python

Tags: python, error-handling

I want to print out ERROR if the variable `sizeOfList` is less than 0, not an integer, or greater than 1000.  This is how I am handling these errors:

```
if sizeOfList > 1000 or not isinstance(sizeOfList,int) or sizeOfList < 0:
    print "ERROR:"
    sys.exit()
```

It works perfectly fine except for when the variable is equal to zero.  It thinks this is an error when I really just want it to print out nothing.  I am really confused on why this is happening and how to fix it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: your question has a syntax error in it.

Comment: That code works fine when `sizeOfList` is zero - the if statement fails. You should revisit your assumptions.

Comment: But when it is zero "ERROR:" is printed and the program exits...why is this?

Comment: When `sizeOfList` is `0`, "ERROR:" is _not_ printed.

Answer (score 0):

> But when it is zero "ERROR:" is printed and the program exits...why is this?

The only way this is possible with the following conditional:

```
sizeOfList > 1000 or not isinstance(sizeOfList,int) or sizeOfList < 0
```

Is if your "zero" value is actually a `string`. Try

```
type(sizeOfList)
```

before your code to verify this.

**Edit:**

Generally you don't want to care about the variable types. Try writing like so:

```
if !sizeOfList.isdigit():
    print "Not a number!"
    sys.exit()

if sizeOfList < 0 or sizeOfList > 1000:
    print "Not in range!"
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: he could use `type cast` in `try` block, it looks more pythonic

Answer (score 0):

Im not exactly sure what you are trying to accomplish but this is one way.

```
>>> def test_list(input):
...     tmp = input
...     while True:
...             if len(input)<=0:
...                     print "out of range"
...                     break
...             else:
...                     print tmp.pop()
...
>>> l = [1,2,3,4,5,5,6]
>>> test_list(l)
6
5
5
4
3
2
1
out of range
```